# Method return Double instead of Integer

Tags: java

```
  private Integer[] array = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

    Number getValueByIndex(int index)
    {
        return (index >= 0 && index < array.length) ? array[index] : new Double(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Number value1 = new Solution().getValueByIndex(5); //-1.0, class java.lang.Double expected
        Number value2 = new Solution().getValueByIndex(2); //3, class java.lang.Integer expected

        System.out.println(value1 + ", " + value1.getClass().toString());
        System.out.println(value2 + ", " + value2.getClass().toString());
    }
```

I can't figure out why the method return Double instead of Integer in the second case.

Comment: *I can't figure out why the method return Double instead of Integer in the second case.* `new Double(-1)`; and a ternary expression **must** return the same type on both sides.

Comment: Which one is the "Second Case" here?

Comment: A ternary expression mustn't return the same type, try this : Object obj = isThisRight ? new String("a String") : new Double(4);
It could be a String or a Double !

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If you have a question about why the code is written like it is, you should address it to the author. It seems pretty strange to me. Also pointless. The array could be replaced by a modulo calculation for example, and there's no reason why -1 needs to be represented as a `Double`. Basically the entire method is unnecessary. I would write it off as just poor coding.

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt I don't know what you mean,. Ternary expressions *must* return the same type: in this case, `Number`.

Comment: I thought that new Solution().getValueByIndex(2).toString()  would be  "3 class java.lang.Integer", but it is not

Comment: So what *is* it? A secret?

Comment: 3.0 java.lang.Double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there are two different types (which are convertible  to numeric types) are being used in conditional expression as the second and third operands.

How the type of a conditional expression is determined is explained here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Answer (score 1):

Arthur, Please check this code section carefully

```
return (index >= 0 && index < array.length) ? array[index] : new Double(-1);
```

It basically translates to

> Return a Double value `new Double(-1)` when you pass a value bigger than size of your "*array*" to the argument "*index*"

Since your method returns a "*Number*" type which is superclass for all number classes, it accepts the value and the toString() print as a decimal value. Hope it helps.
You can checkout the Number class here at the Java API Documentation-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). I am quoting the relevant part here:

> Subclasses of Number must provide methods to convert the represented
>   numeric value to byte, double, float, int, long, and short.

You will definitely get odd behaviour when you don't follow what documentation says. So in your case, if the value is int, you should use [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()), and for double use [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue()).

Comment: @ArturArsalanov please [don't leave a thank you comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184/282546), instead upvote the answer if it was helpful to you. Just [Pay it forward](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)! At least that's how SE works!